# Grunt and UglifyJS - Exclude jQuery functions from minification

Tags: jquery, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

##### Problem

I'm attempting to use [`uglify.js`](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) within a `gruntfile.js`, via the [`grunt-contrib-uglify`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) task, but have encountered an issue whereby references to jQuery functions are being mangled and therefore can't be resolved as a function.

> `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).V is not a function`

Having checked the produced `.min.js` script, I can see the `on(...)` function has been mangled.

```js
$("#myElementId").V("click", function() {
    var e = D.r.M();
    C.r.w(e)
}),
```

##### Attempted Solution

As you can see below, having checked through the docs, I've attempted to exclude this function from the mangling using the `reserved` option, but it doesn't seem to be having an effect.

```js
...
uglify: {
    all: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            nameCache: 'temp/grunt-uglify-cache.json',
            mangle: {
                toplevel: true,
                properties: true,
                reserved: ['jQuery']
            }
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            cwd: 'Content/Scripts/',
            src: ['**/*.js', '!*.min.js'],
            dest: 'Content/Scripts/',
            ext: '.min.js',
        }]
    }
},
...
```

I've also seen suggestions for using `reserved: ['jQuery']` (for example, the [task documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#reserved-identifiers)) but that didn't seem to resolve the issue, either.

Have I missed something in how to use the `uglify` task with scripts containing `jQuery` usages, or is it necessary to exclude `jQuery` or each of its functions we use from mangling?

#### Update #1

Disabling the `properties` mangle option stops the issue, as one might expect, but ideally, I'd like to mangle properties for custom objects but without impacting those jQuery functions (or, mangle them, but map them correctly).

I've since used the `concat` task to combine the essential page layout scripts into a single `app.js` file which is minified with a source map to the source correctly. However, enabling `properties` still causes the above issue with the jQuery functions. Here's how the `uglify` task looks now...

```js
...
uglify: {
    all: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            nameCache: 'temp/grunt-uglify-cache.json',
            mangle: {
                toplevel: true,
                // reserved: ['jQuery'],
                // properties: true,
            }
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            cwd: 'Content/Scripts/',
            src: ['app.js'],
            dest: 'Content/Scripts/',
            ext: '.min.js',
        }]
    }
},
...
```